# Create instance of class based on string for name and array for parameters

Tags: php, class, oop

The title is really explicit, but I am going to give an example:

```
class Foo
{
    public function __construct($param1, $param2) {
        echo 'Class name: ' . __CLASS__ . "\n" .
             'param1 = ' . $param1 . "\n" .
             'param2 = ' . $param2;
    }
}

$class_name = 'Foo';
$params =
    [
    'content1',
    'content2'
    ];
```

Having this code, how can I create an instance of `Foo`, using the parameters in `$params`.

I know I can do

```
$class = new $class_name($params);
```

But this would pass the parameters as one array, I would like it to *expand* the parameters. The following would be the behavior I would like:

```
$class = new $class_name($param[0], $param[1]);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Other than the answer posted, anything else would be a _hack_.  You either want 2 args or you want an array of args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 5.6:

```
$instance = new $class(...$args);
```

If not use reflection:

```
$reflect  = new ReflectionClass($class);
$instance = $reflect->newInstanceArgs($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hesitate to post this because really you should design to either accept an array of parameters or individual parameters.  However, here are to *hackish* ways:

Using another function:

```
public function init($params) {
    echo 'Class name: ' . __CLASS__ . "\n" .
         'param1 = ' . $params[0] . "\n" .
         'param2 = ' . $params[1];
}

public function __construct($param1, $param2=null) {
    if(!is_array($param1)) {
        $param1 = func_get_args();
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($this, 'init'), $param1);
}
```

Doing it all in the `__construct`:

```
public function __construct($param1, $param2=null) {
    if(!is_array($param1)) {
        $param1 = func_get_args();
    }
    echo 'Class name: ' . __CLASS__ . "\n" .
         'param1 = ' . $param1[0] . "\n" .
         'param2 = ' . $param1[1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. My example was only ... an example, I am actually creating a class which executes the specified method in the specified class, and which passes the arguments to this class. This is why I can't modify my *receiving* class.